# How to pass parameters when getting "Odd number of elements in hash assignment"

Tags: perl, rt

I'm doing some template programming in RT (http://bestpractical.com/rt), and it uses Perl.  Unfortunately, I've only dallied with Perl very occasionally.

I'm trying to call a sub procedure that starts off with:

```
sub PrepareEmailUsingTemplate {
    my %args = (
        Template => '',
        Arguments => {},
        @_
    );
```

Since this is a part of the lib, I don't get to change it.

The call I'm making to it is:

```
my ($template, $msg) = RT::Interface::Email->PrepareEmailUsingTemplate( 
    Template => 'CCReplyFirstMessage' );
return (0, $msg) unless $template;
```

And I'm getting  "Odd number of elements in hash assignment at /opt/rt4/sbin/../lib/RT/Interface/Email.pm line 552. (/opt/rt4/sbin/../lib/RT/Interface/Email.pm:552), with is the first line of the sub.

I know I'm doing something whacky in passing the parameter.  How should I be passing it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`PrepareEmailUsingTemplate`](https://github.com/bestpractical/rt/blob/0348c917086785bedaa775491b84a175de26eb2b/lib/RT/Interface/Email.pm#L494) is not a class method, it is a simple function. You want to call it like this:

```
my ($template, $msg) = RT::Interface::Email::PrepareEmailUsingTemplate( 
    Template => 'CCReplyFirstMessage' );
return (0, $msg) unless $template;
```

When you call it with the `->`, your `@_` will end up with **three** values: your two for the hash and the class name at the beginning. The result of calling it as a class method will be something like this:

```
my %args = (
    Template => '',
    Arguments => {},
    'RT::Interface::Email::PrepareEmailUsingTemplate',
    Template => 'CCReplyFirstMessage'
);
```

And that's where your "odd number of elements in hash assignment" error comes from.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation of what @_ means in the context of ->.

Comment: @Reuben: The [`@_` array](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40ARG) is the argument list for the function, functions are variadiac in Perl (with exceptions of course) so you get all your parameters in `@_` and then you unpack them by hand.

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
my ($template, $msg) = RT::Interface::Email::PrepareEmailUsingTemplate(Template => 'CCReplyFirstMessage');
```

The function isn't written to be called with `->`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to call the sub as a class method, you need to expect the additional implicit class argument:

```
my $class = shift;
my %args = ( ..., @_ );
```